# Why is the code inside RxJS Observable constructor not being called?

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs, ionic2

If I do this in browser console, the constructor function doesnot seems to be called-

```
Observable.create(observer =>
   console.log('this is the observer'); //doesn't gets logged
   this.alertObserver = observer
);
```

or this :-

```
new Observable(observer =>
   console.log('this is the observer'); //doesn't gets logged
   this.alertObserver = observer
);
```

I have tried importing Observer through

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

but with no help.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rx observables are lazy loaded. You need at least one subscriber.

Try:

```
var observable = Observable.create(observer =>
   console.log('this is the observer'); 
   this.alertObserver = observer
);
observable.subscribe();
```

Comment: This worked. But I am aware that observable are lazy, I have been calling a function which would create the observable and return it. Something like this -  

showAlert(title){
      var promise$ = Observable.create(obsvr =>
             this.alertObsvr = obsvr
        );
       var self = this;
        var alert = Alert.create({...
                handler: function (data) {
                    self.alertObsvr.next('c');
                }
            }]
        });
        this.nav.present(alert);
       return promise$;

And then showInfoAlert(...).subscribe(..

Somehow it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

Not this:

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

This:
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

Comment: Hi Chuck, first of all, welcome to Stack Overflow! Good answers but could you explain the above code a little bit more for more the junior devs? Thanks!